# Is there any way to expand the body of `NewDocumentCommand` at definition time?

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion

Is there way to expand the body passed to `NewDocumentCommand` at the point of definition? Ideally, just expanded the once.

Here is my (minimalised) scenario.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand*{\baz}{\foo}
\newcommand*{\expandme}{good}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:NV \NewDocumentCommand \baz { s D<>{} } {
    \expandme% Should get expanded once at definition time.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*{\expandme}{bad}

\begin{document}

    \foo<bar>% Prints "bad", but I want it to print "good".

\end{document}
```

Making the following modification yields an `Undefined control sequence` error, presumably because `\exp_args` is having a hard time with the `{ s D<>{} }` argument.

```latex
\exp_args:NVNo \NewDocumentCommand \baz { s D<>{} } {
    \expandme% Should get expanded once at definition time.
}
```

Finally, note that the following solution, which works in the simplest case, but is problematic when `\bar` can take a number of values, and this code is repeated for each (as is my real scenario).

```latex
\exp_args:NNV \cs_set:Npn \tmp \expandme
% alternatively to the above line, I think: \edef\tmp\expandme
\exp_args:NV \NewDocumentCommand \baz { s D<>{} } {
    \tmp
}
```

Comment: `{ s D<>{} } ` needs to be n not N

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I forgot to adjust that bit of code while testing. Don’t help though.

Comment: Doesn't help though. *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\expanded` in recent tex releases:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand*{\baz}{\foo}
\newcommand*{\expandme}{good}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\expanded{\noexpand\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter\noexpand\baz { s D<>{} } {
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\expandme}% Should get expanded once at definition time.
}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*{\expandme}{bad}

\begin{document}

    \foo<bar>% Prints "bad", but I want it to print "good".

\end{document}
```

---

Or you can package it up as a custom VnV argument list

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand*{\baz}{\foo}
\newcommand*{\expandme}{good}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args_generate:n{VnV}
\exp_args:NVnV\NewDocumentCommand\baz { s D<>{} } \expandme
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*{\expandme}{bad}

\begin{document}

    \foo<bar>% Prints "bad", but I want it to print "good".

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Skillmon I updated

Comment: Two interesting solutions -- thank you. I didn't know about `\expanded` or `\unexpanded`, but they seem handy. In this case, I find the the former solution to be clever but took me a few minutes to understand the first time. The second solution seems more elegant and just as good, as long as one is familiar with expl3 syntax. I presume `\cs_new:Npn \exp_args:NVnV {\::V \::n \::V \::: }` specifies the types of the parameters in reverse due to associativity?

Comment: @Noldorin `\unexpanded` is standard etex so has been available for decades, `\expanded` came from a never distributed pdftex branch that was picked up in luatex so was luatex only until last year when it was back ported to all the texlive engines so pdftex, xetex, ptex as well as luatex

Comment: `\exp_args_generate:n` is in the kernel for a reason…

Comment: @egreg done....

Comment: @egreg Ah, even better, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason the needed `\exp_args:N...` variant isn't available, you can help yourself with `\use:n`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand*{\baz}{\foo}
\newcommand*{\expandme}{good}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:Nno \use:n { \exp_args:NV \NewDocumentCommand \baz { s D<>{} } } {
    \expandme% Should get expanded once at definition time.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*{\expandme}{bad}

\begin{document}

    \foo<bar>% Prints "bad", but I want it to print "good".

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, this is very useful to know about `\use:n` and how it can serve in such situations. Thank you.

Comment: @Noldorin it's a trick I often use when defining `expl3` functions at low-level code. For example I might use something like `\exp_args:Nno \use:n { \cs_new:Npn \module_function:w #1#2\foo\bar } { \__module_tmp: }`.

Comment: Not sure exactly what that does, but looks quite clever. Is there a reason to prefer your solution over David's second solution, incidentally?

Comment: @Noldorin except that the `\::` macros are documented as "shouldn't be used outside this module" no, not really. The pseudo-code above just does one step of expansion for the definition of `\module_function:w`, which has a long argument list, so using `\exp_args:N...` becomes more or less impossible.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: There is `\exp_args_generate:n`

Comment: @egreg tell that to David :) For this it might be practical, but generally I prefer my `\use:n` workaround.

Comment: @Skillmon No; `\exp_args:N...` and variants are made just to avoid such tricks. And you say “If for some reason the needed `\exp_args:N...` variant isn't available”: in this case `\exp_args_generate:n` is the answer.

Comment: @egreg sure, let's go and do `\exp_args_generate:n { NNNNNNNNNo }`... Just to use it one single time for something that could be done much easier, in an easier to maintain way. I agree that there are variants for which `\exp_args_generate:n` is the answer, but it's not *always* the answer.

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry, I heartily disagree.

Answer (score 3):

You should define an interface for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\expandme}{good}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommandExpandOnce
 {
  \exp_args:NNno \NewDocumentCommand
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommandExpandOnce \foo { s D<>{} } {%
  \expandme% Should get expanded once at definition time.
}

\renewcommand*{\expandme}{bad}

\begin{document}

\foo<bar>% Prints "bad", but I want it to print "good".

\end{document}
```

You can check that the output is “good”.

Comment: Thanks -- though I think this is an ancillary point, no? The core thing seems to be `\exp_args_generate:n{VnV}`.

Comment: @Noldorin not really: the final V form isn't used here, egreg's version uses a braced form that expands the content (which is \expandme` here) once and re-braces it. I used a final V argument where the final argument is necessarily a single token (`\expandme` in this case)  also here (as in my first version) it just answers the question in the title (expanding the body) not  simultaneously expanding the command name once (which could be done by replacing `NNno`  here by `NVno`)

Comment: Yeah, though central to my issue was expanding the command name once at the same time. Admittedly, that's not in my title (would have made it too long I thought), though it seems to have been the root cause of my problem: that the `\exp_args:NVnV` variant does not exist by default. Anyway, this is a nice answer regardless, and supplements the other two. Now I don't know whether to give you or egreg the answer, since I decided on your (2nd) solution, but then it got amended to egreg's suggest (`\exp_args_generate:n{VnV}`) hah.

Comment: ... in any case, thanks to all three of you for your helpful answers.